# How to merge two arrays in a plist?

Tags: iphone, xcode, merge, plist

I have a plist with two string arrays.  I want to merge these two arrays.  I tried selecting all the strings in one array and copying to the other, but I cant select multiple items.  I don't want to do this programmatically.  I'm on a Mac using xcode.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see why is was voted as off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit the PList files as text (context menu, *"Open as plain text file"* or *"Source code file"*) and copy the relevant items in.

Answer (score 0):

Save the plist in XML format if it isn't already, then open it as text. If you understand XML, it's pretty straightforward to move all the string nodes from one array to the other, then just remove the unwanted array node.